# How to add custom button to edit attribute form

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.2

How to add custom button to edit attribute form?

[image]

Comment: which magento version?

Comment: Magento version is 2.2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <plugin name="add_custom_button_attribute" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Widget\Context" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now Create **VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Widget/Context.php**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Widget;

class Context
{
    public function afterGetButtonList(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject,
        $buttonList
    ) {
        if($subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_attribute_edit'){
            $buttonList->add(
                'custom_button',
                [
                    'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                    'onclick' => "setLocation('window.location.href')",
                    'class' => 'save'
                ]
            );
        }

        return $buttonList;
    }
}
```

**Tested with Magento 2.2.x**

Clear cache.

Comment: If you have time plz.. look on to my thread? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204627/cron-job-not-working-in-my-live-magento-2-website