# Cron job not working in my live magento 2 website

Tags: magento-2.1, cron

Today I set the `Cron` job for every 2 **Minutes**, but it's not working. You can see my setup in `Nexcess` Siteworx panel image below.

[image]

I need to clear the `debug.log` and other files every 2 minutes. Is it the correct way or need to modify my rule.

Comment: @SohelRana Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your ssh and type `whereisphp` you will get path , In root folder type `crontab-e` it will show all the cron set, paste the code inside that and save it. For example for reindex 2 mins once,

```
*/2 * * * * /opt/nexcess/php56u/root/usr/bin/php /home/public_html/html/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Replace your php path `/opt/nexcess/php56u/root/usr/bin/php`

Comment: If I want clear the `debug.log` file. what is the rule?

Comment: Add this in your custom file file_put_contents("".dirname(__DIR__)."/var/log/debug.log", "");